# Some beginner questions about elf files, sections headers and how they work in general when we run an application

Tags: elf

I'm learning about the elf file. I read some stuff on it and I'm starting to understand very very little about it however something is puzzeling me. I want to continue learning it and mastering it but first I want to make sure I got the most simple things right. I will state what I know below please correct me where I'm making a mistake.

When you write a C application and you compile it(say with gcc) it gets translated into machine instructions which represent code and data.
The output of invoking the compiler is an elf file.
The elf file contains(among other things) a section header which is basically a series of Elf64_Shdr each for every section your compiled application contains. 
**So basically a section is just some machine instructions which represent either code or data and some info about it like where it(address of first instruction) is and how long it is(size), whether it is writable or readable(some flags), etc.** Is my understanding of sections and section header correct?

When we run the make command and pass it the elf file the linker comes into play and looks at all sections created by the compiler, at their names and attributes and groups them into 'segments' following the rules of a ld script file and creates the executable file which we can run **So basically segments are nothing more than sections of same attributes grouped togheter in a common section with a specific name.** Is this correct?

**Then when we actually run the created executable the loader comes into play and looks at these segments created by the linker and by reading this information which they contain it maps the machine instructions to various memory locations so the process can run. This is what is called(in my understanding) a memory image.** Is this correct?

Thank you for reading and helping me clear my doubts thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple inaccuracies in your description, and it's unclear whether you are imprecise in understanding the processing involved, or in *describing* them.

> When you write a C application and you compile it(say with gcc) it gets translated into machine instructions which represent code and data.

This isn't entirely accurate: there is a difference between "machine instructions" and "machine code".

When you compile a `.c` file, some compilers will translate it into machine instructions (assembly), and then pass it to assembler to produce machine code (GCC does that). Other compilers have integrated assembler, and effectively skip the assembly generation step (Clang does that).

> The output of invoking the compiler is an elf file.

On *some* but not *all* systems, the result of compilation is a relocatable ELF file. Other systems produce object files in a different format, such as XCOFF or Mach-O.

> The elf file contains(among other things) a section header which is basically a series of Elf64_Shdr each for every section your compiled application contains.

The *application* is not built yet, so this is inaccurate. Also, `Elf64_Shdr` only applies to 64-bit ELF platforms; on 32-bit machines it's `Elf32_Ehdr`.

> When we run the make command

The `make` command has *nothing* to do with anything. It just invokes compiler and linker (or other tools) as appropriate. You can replace it with a shell script, or just type the commands by hand.

> and pass it the elf file

The link step involves one or *more* (usually more) relocatable `ELF` object files, archive libraries and dynamic libraries.

> the linker comes into play and looks at all sections created by the compiler, at their names and attributes and groups them into 'segments' following the rules of a ld script file

To understand what the linker does you can read this [series of blog posts](https://lwn.net/Articles/276782/).

Your description trivializes what the linker does. The linker is much more complicated, and performs relocation resolution which you didn't mention, and many other tasks.

> and creates the executable file which we can run.

Usually true.

You can ask linker to combine several relocatable object files into a *combined* object file (with `ld -r foo.o bar.o -o combined.o`), and in that case the result will *not* be an executable file.

You can also ask the linker to link a shared library instead of linking an executable.

> So basically segments are nothing more than sections of same attributes grouped togheter in a common section with a specific name.

False. There is *lot* more to linking than grouping sections together.

> Then when we actually run the created executable the loader comes into play

The loader only comes into play for dynamically-linked executables. Fully-static executables do not have a loader, and are started directly by the kernel itself.

> and looks at these segments created by the linker and by reading this information which they contain it maps the machine instructions to various memory locations so the process can run. This is what is called(in my understanding) a memory image.

Mostly correct. Some parts of the memory image do not come from disk at all (e.g. thread-local storage and contents of combined `.bss` sections)